# Android ViewPager preloading too much fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager

A ViewPager preloads fragments.

But with a pageWidth=0.5 (2 fragments per screen), I think it loads too much views before the current position...

[image: fff]
I have `pageLimit=1` and `pageWidth=0.5`.
It should be ok to preload LEFT1 and LEFT2, but why LEFT3 ?
LEFT3 is not on the next left screen...

I tried to understand ViewPager.java from support v4:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/support-library-27.1.1/core-ui/src/main/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#1155

line 1155, it says

> // Fill 3x the available width or up to the number of offscreen
>   // pages requested to either side, whichever is larger.
>   But for multiple fragments per screen, it loads more before than current and after the current position.

With the Google sample project https://github.com/googlesamples/android-SlidingTabsBasic/
adding

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   [...]
   mViewPager.setCurrentItem(25);

@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
     // 2 fragments per screen
     return .5f;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // 50 fragments
    return 50;
}
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    [...]
    Log.d("debugpageviewer", "position="+position);
}
```

And it loads 7 fragments (3 before current position). The smaller the pageWidth, the more fragments are loaded before.

So, is this a bug or did I miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling [`setOffscreenPageLimit()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) on your ViewPager in your onCreate method.

For example `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)` will make sure that no more than 3 fragments are always kept around: the current one and the two adjacent ones.

Comment: Yes I tried this, and the default is 1. But the condition to continue to create views is the `extraWidthLeft >= leftWidthNeeded` #1166. So more fragments than the setOffscreenPageLimit are created.

Answer (score 0):

You shall use `ViewPager2` with `FragmentStateAdapter`. See official explanation here:

Use ViewPager2 to slide between fragments: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/screen-slide-2

Migrate from ViewPager to ViewPager2: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/vp2-migration